# Sending audio/wav file through Twilio MMS

Tags: php, twilio, wav, twilio-php, mms

I have a special case situation, where I'm trying to forward voicemail files that come encoded from a system as type "audio/wav" as an MMS to a phone number using the Twilio SMS/MMS API. I am using PHP 8.0 to try to accomplish this.

I did see that "audio/wav" is not a supported file type, and I confirmed this when trying to send the MMS using the API and the message failed due to the unsupported file type.

```
Msg "Attempt to retrieve MediaUrl returned an unsupported Content-Type."
EmailNotification   "false"
contentType "audio/wav"
url "https://URL/test.wav"
LogLevel    "ERROR"
```

1. I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a workaround for this issue, or knows of possible solutions.
2. Are audio/wav not supported, because carriers don't support this format as mms?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs WAV is supported

[Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types)

audio/vnd.wave is a wave media type

[Wiki source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)

**In the MMS docs page**

If the content-type header of your MediaUrl does not match the media at that URL, Twilio will reject the request.

Make sure you have set the correct content type.

[Source](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-python)

Comment: Yes, I see audio/vnd.wave is supported, but the file that I have to send is read as content-type audio/wav and gets rejected with the error in my post, because audio/wav is not supported. I was wondering how to change the content-type header to audio/vnd.wave if possible.

Comment: How are you serving the audio file?