# Sending Audio via Text using Twilio Connection in Make.com

Tags: automation, twilio, sms, mms, make.com

I'm using Make.com (Zapier alternative) to automate the sending of a text.

Is there a way to send an audio file, actually playable in the text via Twilio using a tool like Zapier or Make.com?

I'm not much of a developer so using the API to send via PHP, Javascript or Python is a bit intimidating, would love to figure it out through a UI tool.

I have the audio file that I want to send via text uploaded to Google Drive (audio/mpeg).

I can send a link to the audio file just fine (Web View Link), but I'm hoping there is a way to actually embed the audio into the text message itself.

Using the "Media URL" throws an error showing "Invalid Content-Type".  In Make.com, the Media URL looks like it can only be an image (gif,png,jpeg).
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post might help: ["Sending audio/wav file through Twilio MMS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708835/sending-audio-wav-file-through-twilio-mms)

Especially this part:

> In the MMS docs page
>
> If the content-type header of your MediaUrl does not match the media
> at that URL, Twilio will reject the request.
>
> Make sure you have set the correct content type.

If it is Twilio returning the "Invalid Content-Type" error, it is likely from an incorrect or unspecified content type. I do not know how you specify a content-type with make.com and it could also be that that the audio file you are trying to send isn't actually an MP3 or a WAV.

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is referring to the PHP API and also doesn’t have a solution attached.

Comment: I edit my answer with the quote that should help. The library doesn't matter so much for the errors that Twilio is throwing.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  It definitely appears that the Content-Type is not matching, or not being set.  So the question is, how do I set the content-type via Make.com (or Zapier if that's better)?

Comment: @JWTechDesign, glad I got you pointed in the right direction. Please accept my response as an answer. For your next question, check if stack overflow has a make.com or zapier.com forum who might answer those questions.